# Can an iOS app that has access to Photos get all my photos?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, photos, photos.app

Can a developer collect my photos that I edited and saved in my iPhone album?

One of the function of the an app I am using is to edit photos and save them to my iPhone's album. In this case, can the developer collect my edited photos?

I did not upload any photos, nor did I share them with anybody.

Also, there is no mention of collecting user's content in the privacy policy of the said app.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 26):

Yes, if you give the application access to your photos and the application has network access, the photos *can* be taken from your iPhone.

## Only use apps you trust

- If you do not trust the developer, do not install or use their applications.
- If the developer is not clear and explicit about how they handle your photos, do not install or use their applications.
- If the developer is not contactable or does not answer your questions, do not install or use their applications.

Comment: Good to hear it helps. Even Apple has problems detecting bad behaviour with apps they review. As a user, it is worth being careful. Once your photos leave your iPhone, there is little practical you can do to get them back under your control.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, the developer could theoretically collect photos that you edit within the app.

If you have granted the app access to your Photos library explicitly, then the app could potentially also collect those photos. If the app uses the Apple supplied image picker control, it can get a copy of a single photo that you select without you giving explicit access to the whole of the Photos library. This way the app can only access that single photo.

If the app does not explicitly state about such a collection clearly to the users, and it is not written in the app's privacy policy, such a collection would be a violation of their agreement with Apple - and depending on your jurisdiction - most likely also a violation of the law.

I don't think there's necessarily any greater chance of a single person business violating rules and regulations than a company doing so. In some way, you could argue that it would be the other way around, as a named person could be less inclined to do shady stuff compared to an "anonymous" company not clearly linked with one or more individuals.

You can try to monitor the network traffic made by the app using a network mirror, a packet dumper or a proxy such [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org) (can be downloaded for free using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) on a Mac). However, it is really difficult to ascertain whether or not your photos are being collected. The reason is that apps today are required to use encryption for network transfers, and as such, it can be difficult or impossible to identify your photos from other network traffic made by the app.

However, if you're certain that the app is not supposed to use any network traffic - and traffic only occurs when you select a photo, and the amount of data matches your photo, it would be a strong indication that your photo is being uploaded somewhere.

In any case, if you have a strong suspicion of foul play, then contact Apple. They have the means to investigate and ultimately remove offending apps from the App Store.

Comment: Thank you! And I do not suspect the app but I just want to know whether it is possible in general. Because I heard Apple is conducting comprehensive examination on all of the apps before they are registered on App store.

Comment: Apple does do a review of every app that is on the App Store. However, such a review does not in any way guarantee that an app developer abides by all rules. It is easy to get an app through the review, and later activate collection of images. Such attempts to circumvent Apple's review process would ofcourse be against the developer agreement, and the developer would risk termination of their agreement - including having all apps removed from the App Store.

Comment: It was actually me who mentioned that. And ofcourse you have a choice - you can just close the picker without choosing a picture.

Answer (score 3):

If an app allows you to edit photos, then yes of course it has access to your photos and can store them locally (or transmit them), would be rather difficult to modify photos otherwise. There is a whole bunch of apps in the Store who do exactly that (Google Photos, VSCO etc.).

If you suspect the app to upload photos without you knowing it may be worthwile to monitor its network traffic with tools like [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) or [Proxyman](https://proxyman.io/), and inform Apple if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

### Ask the developer

> Can a developer collect my photos that I edited and saved in my iPhone album?

In theory yes. An app that has access to your photos can read (obviously to work on them) and transmit it elsewhere (more so if it depends on an active Internet connection to provide a necessary functionality). You should consider contacting the developer and asking the question to them.

> Also, there is no mention of collecting user's content in the privacy policy of the said app.

Some answers have mentioned an approach involving analysing outgoing network traffic from the app. While it may help you establishing your belief to a certain degree, it may not be a straightforward thing to do if you are not technically savvy enough to do so. Network traffic analysis may not be a very simple thing to interpret for a casual user.

Instead you could start by carefully reading through the app privacy policy and understanding what the developer says about handling users personal data.

If you do not get a conclusive explanation, I'd advise you consider contacting the developer of the app with your concerns. **The way developer responds to the communication could help you get a much better clarity for your query**.

If the developer doesn't respond to the communication for a reasonable time, you could consider raising your concern to Apple.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more safety net here. Every iOS app, when submitted to the App Store, goes through a review process. If developers are doing anything shady in the background like transfering data straight after granting access to your Photos library without stating a reason for it clearly, Apple can reject the app and it won’t show up in the App Store.

Comment: For the most serious cases, Apple can pull the app from the AppStore, revoke its Certificate so it won’t run anymore, refund the full purchase price to all buyers and get the _full_ purchase price back from the developer, not just the 70% the developer received, and then cancel the developer account without any refund, which will remove the developer’s other apps. You’d have to do something pretty serious for that.

Comment: What if he hid the fact?  I read a comment: Apple does do a review of every app that is on the App Store. However, such a review does not in any way guarantee that an app developer abides by all rules. It is easy to get an app through the review, and later activate the collection of images:  Does it mean there could be a lot of ios developers abusing this fact?

Comment: I’d rather doubt @JAKE but I think thats just my opinion. It ends up in giving trust to the developer/publisher

Answer (score -1):

Does the app require network permissions? Photo editing can be done locally, without network access (at least, in theory). So, if the app doesn't need network permissions, it may be safer to use, in the sense that it would not be able to communicate with a server outside your phone, so cannot transmit your photos or data about your photos, to any server.

Comment: How can you prevent an app from accessing the network?